# Can I add a search box that will open a new page on some 3rd party site to Google Docs?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to make a document/spreadsheet containing a few resources I regularly use and perform searches in.  Can I create something I can perform searches directly from a document that will open up the results on the third-party website in a new window?

e.g.:

1. Type `mysearch` into something (cell, text box, etc) and
2. Have it open `http://www.pdb.org/pdb/search/navbarsearch.do?inputQuickSearch=mysearch` in a new window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is as close as I could get to what your after

using a spreadsheet I created a "search button"

with the following formula within it:

```
=HYPERLINK("www.example.com?search=" & B19,"Search")
```

This then creates a hyper link to your site so then when the user clicks the cell it will have the  "go to link" thing that the doc does by default.